# How can Spring RestController accept both JSON and XML?

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I have a Spring controller that works great:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/widgets")
class WidgetController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    WidgetResponse createWidget(@Valid @RequestBody Widget widget) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here I can POST a JSON message and my widget instance gets created:

```
{
  "name" : "Widget1",
  "type" : "spinning",
  "isFizz" : true
}
```

I would like this endpoint to also accept and deserialize XML widgets like so:

```
<widget name="Widget1">
  <type>spinning</type>
  <isFizz>false</isFizz>
</widget>
```

I'm trying to figure out:

- How to allow the endpoint to accept **both** JSON and XML data, and deserialize them properly; and
- How to validate any XML against a Schema, such as `widgets.xsd`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the parameter `consumes` of annotation `@RequestMapping`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/widgets",consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
WidgetResponse createWidget(@Valid @RequestBody Widget widget){
///
{
```

The parameter consumes takes an array of MediaType