# Can REST POST endpoint defined with java spring accept both XML and JSON

Tags: java, spring, deserialization

I found that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597140/how-can-spring-restcontroller-accept-both-json-and-xml) way i can make the service to accept both XML and JSON, but how do i have to set up the data class for it? Does it need both the XML and JSON annotation? Or does it need something special to work?

Comment: Look at jackson for json and xml data annotations together with spring boot. http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-content-negotiation-with-xml-json-representations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Consumes` annotation to pass an array of accepted MIME types:

> The value of @Consumes is an array of String of acceptable MIME types. For example:
>   @Consumes({"**text/plain**, **text/html**"})

from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html